# How to get exact number of line from where the method called in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to get the exact number of line from where the method is being called.

I have a single method which is called multiple line in the command from different different lines. So, I need to get the line from its being called in the `Controller`.

I have used the  following code from `Stack Overflow`, but this is passing me the wrong line number:

```
NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Example: 1   UIKit                               0x00540c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
    [array removeObject:@""];

    NSLog(@"Stack = %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"Framework = %@", [array objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog(@"Memory address = %@", [array objectAtIndex:2]);
    NSLog(@"Class caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:3]);
    NSLog(@"Function caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:4]);
    NSLog(@"Line caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:5]);
```

So, how to get exact number of line from where the method called in iOS?

Answer (score -1):

```
NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: This will not give the line number from which the method is called, but the line number in the source file of the NSLog.